# facing some issue related to codeigniter url routing

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I just want to show the url `websitename/common_controller/about` as `websitename/about`

I did like this in the config/routes.php

```
$route['about'] = "common_controller/about";
```

But it is not working. please help me.

Comment: did you set default route in route.php file?

Comment: yes. but when i set it like $route['common_controller/about'] = 'about';  getting error: 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
$route['common_controller/about'] = 'about';
```

if you method takes input you can write

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'method_name/$1';
```